# Can Kripke structures have guards?

Tags: verification, model-checking, nusmv

I have a simple kripke structure, where I have 3 states, with the following transitions:

```
s1 --> s2
s2 --> s1
s1 --> s3
s3 --> s3
```

s1 is the only initial state. I do not want the loop s1 to s2 be repeated more than a certain amount (say twice). In other transition systems, I could add a guard on the transition.

Q1: Can Kripke structures have guards on transitions?

Q2: If yes, how can I model it in NuSmv?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing apples and oranges here. The model with guards (e.g. in NuSMV) defines a state space which again can be seen as a Kripke structure (let's ignore issues like deadlocks here).

Guards are an element of a modelling approach, whereas the Kripke structure is the underlying theoretical concept that is used to describe the state space.

Let's take an example: We have a model with a variable `v` that can take two values 1 and 2 with 1 as the initial value, and two transitions with guards:

```
a == WHEN v=1 THEN v:=2
b == WHEN v=2 THEN v:=1
```

The resulting state space would be:

```
[v=1] --> [v=2]
[v=2] --> [v=1]
```

That is actually a Kripke structure (with `[v=1]` as the only initial state and without any labels defined on the nodes) that does not contain any guards.

**Update**:
An example for set of labels for each node would be all Boolean expressions that evaluate to true there.

To summarize this for your two questions:

1. No, Kripke structures itself do not have guards.
2. Nevertheless (as explained, no guards in Kripke structures do not mean that there must not be guards in the model), I think you can regard the conditions in the case statement as a guard for the action right of the colon. Or with TRANS you have the guards implicit in the expression.